# Datatable 1.10 can't hide columns when initialization

Tags: javascript, datatable

I use Datatable with serverside, here is my config :

```
var table = $('.table-hover').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: 'http://127.0.0.1:8084/getData',
    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    stateSave: true,
    aLengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100], [25, 50, 100]],
    aPageLength: 25,
    columnDefs: [ {
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets:   0
    }, {
        targets: -1, visible: false
    }],
    select: {
        style:    'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    columns: [
        { title: "", data: "id", name: "id", searchable: true},
        { title: "Nom", data: "video_filename", name: "video.filename", searchable: true},
        { title: "Suivi", data: "status_show", name: "status", searchable: true},
        { title: "Titre", data: "video_titre", name: "video.titre", searchable: true},
        { title: "Waou", data: "waou_show", name: "waou", searchable: true},
        { title: "Note Jury / 20", data: "note_jury", name: "note_jury", searchable: true},
        { title: "Commentaire", data: "comment", name: "comment", searchable: true},
        { title: "Ordre de passage", data: "order", name: "order", searchable: true},
        { title: "Actions", data: "actions", name: "actions", searchable: true},
        { title: "Catégorie", data: "categories", name: "categories", searchable: true},
        { title: "Département", data: "auteur.codepostal", name: "auteur.codepostal", searchable: true},
    ]
});
```

I don't know why, the `targets: -1, visible: false` isn't working. The column is visible anyway.

But if I put :

```
table.column( -1 ).visible(false);
```

After, it works, columns is not visible anymore. Why ? Is is possible to hide columns using serverside ?

Comment: columns are zero indexed. there is no `-1`.

Comment: You can use negative : https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets

Comment: i stand corrected.

Comment: I think its because of the `stateSave: true` .... It keeped columns ...